# Django ORM count or get precentage report

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have three models named Category, Account, and AccountCategory. I need to be able to generate a report wherein I can show the number of which each account was categorized. (e.g let's say I have 10 accounts, then I have three categories (A, B, C) I need to be able to show a piechart)

Account has a many-to-many relationship with Category and AccountCategory is the junction table.

Ideally, I need to have a result of

| Name | Slug | Percentage | Num of Accounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 40% | 4 |
| B | b | 10% | 1 |
| C | c | 50% | 5 |

I was able to get the raw Query but I still need to get the total number of accounts so I can get the percentage I'm struggling with how to do this on ORM.

Basically, I did query the categories, joined account categories, and did a distinct on the account so it won't return the duplicates and then just total the result. For the ORM I think I need to filter the account categories to only return the latest account category per account and then total it but I can't seem to write the exact query using ORM I tried using the Subquery and Prefetch but no avail.

Comment: Can you use queryset annotate (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use annotate method in django orm for this

example :

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Value

queryset = YourModel.objects.filter().annotate(percentage = Concat('count',Value('%'))).values_list('name','slug','numofaccounts', 'percentage')
```